# AMPScript and API Consume

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a process that i need to send a email message to almost 2 million records, but i have to update a campaign at Salesforce Sales Cloud too.

One month ago i need to did this too and i did trough Journey Builder (membercampaign activity) and i noticed that the API Calls worked with almost 100% in my stack. So now i want to use the AMPScript (CreateSalesforceObject) to do this like i can not use the Data Loader.

Will present the same 'problem'?

Comment: I apologize but I am not quite following your question. Can you provide more details on what you used previously and the issue you had and want to avoid in this run as well as how exactly you want to use the AMPscript SF function? (in Email? on Cloudpage as middleware? etc...)

Comment: I will send a email message with the ampscript to update the salesforce campaign member.

Comment: That’s not a good idea, the send will take forever if you try to update 2 mil records in Sales Cloud using AMPscript from an email. The API consume problem you mentioned - did you get an email saying that all tracking data synch will be held for 6 hours or so?